# setting values [jquery or javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an input box, and when a user types something in it I want a second textarea change its value to match that of the input's, on click.  How can I do this using javascript, jquery, or something simpler, or php...

Here's my code:

This is the first input:

```
<form class="form1" action=../search.php method="post">
<input class="askInput" type="text" name="q" value="Search for tags and users or ask a question" onclick="if(this.value == 'Search for tags and users or ask a question') this.value='';"  onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value='Search for tags and users or ask a question';"></input>
                    <input class="searchEnter" type="image" name="submit" src="../Images/askQuestion.png"></input></form>
```

This is the textarea:

```
<div id="askCenter">
<img class="close" src="../Images/closeAsk.png"></img>
<h1><img src="../Images/askQuestionTitle.png" alt="Ask this question"></img></h1>
<textarea></textarea>
<span class="holder"><input type="text" value="add tags" onclick="if(this.value == 'add tags') this.value='';"  onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value='add tags';"></input>
<span class="note">&#8727; Tags are separated by commas</span>

</span>
<input class="askAway" type="image" src="../Images/askAway.png" alt="Ask away"/>
```

Comment: What mark-up are you working with?

Comment: php and html is i understand what your asking

Comment: Not really, I'm asking what the html of your `form` element looks like. The rendered html, as seen by the browser, since that's what JavaScript (and, jQuery is only JavaSCript) works on, and with.

Comment: The user types into the `input` of `name="q"`, and that text should appear in the `textarea` inside of the `div` of `id="askCenter"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TRY IT HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/krmby/EZszM/)

HTML MARKUP

```
<input type="text" id="inputField"></textarea>
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#inputField').keyup(function() {
        $('#textArea').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you bring the relevant jQuery, or JavaScript, in-line with your answer?

Comment: sweeeeeeeeeeeeet.  (had to have lots of characters to reach the limit)

Comment: I'd go easy with the caps lock key ;)

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing your mark-up, something like this would work, albeit it's not tailored to your needs:

```
$('#first').keypress(
    function(e){
        var string = $(this).val();
        $('#textarea').val(string);
    });

$('form').submit(
    function(){
        return false;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LUACj/).

---

With your updated question, with the html from your `form`s:

```
$('input:text[name="q"]').keypress(
    function(e){
        $('#askCenter').find('textarea').val($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: I'd use a different variable name. But +1 for generality!

Comment: @hubrid, you're very welcome, glad to have been of service :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('txt2').value=this.value;"/>
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
```